# database field value that matches to every query

Tags: python, web2py

I would like to insert records into a sqlite database with fields such that every query that specifies a value for that field does not disqualify the record.

```
Make Model  Engine Parameter
Ford *      *          1
Ford Taurus *          2
Ford Escape *          3
```

So a query = (database.table.Make == Ford') & (database.table.Model == 'Taurus') would return the first two records

EDIT: thanks to woot, I decided to use the following: (database.table.Make.belongs('Ford','*')) & (database.table.Model.belongs('Taurus','*')) which is the syntax for the IN operator in web2py

Comment: Do the asterisks represent NULL values?

Comment: Anthony - yes, the '*' are the fields that will not have a value, but I would like to keep the record in the solution set if it passes the other tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?  It won't perform well due to the `OR`s if you have a lot of rows.

```
SELECT *
FROM Cars
WHERE ( Cars.Make = 'Ford' OR Cars.Make = '*' )
AND   ( Cars.Model = 'Taurus' OR Cars.Model = '*' )
```

[Here is a SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1cc2e/1).

If you meant to use `NULL`, you can just replace that and replace the OR condition with `OR Cars.Make IS NULL`, etc.

Or to make it maybe a little less verbose:

```
SELECT *
FROM Cars
WHERE Cars.Make IN ('Ford','*')
AND   Cars.Model IN ('Taurus','*')
```

But you wouldn't be able to use NULL in this case and would have to use the `*` token.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1cc2e/2)

Comment: This was my original idea, but I found the syntax to be verbose, as I will need to repeat this pattern for 4+ columns.

Comment: It'll be this pattern or something equally as verbose I think. If I think of another method I'll update.

Comment: You could do `Cars.Make IN ('Ford','*')`, if that's any better.